# What to do when dput() doesn't work?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, traminer

I usually use `dput()` to a) save R objects, and b) to understand their internal structure. However, in the TraMineR package I encounter something I haven't seen before:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal.tse)
actcal.seqe <- seqecreate(id = actcal.tse$id, 
timestamp = actcal.tse$time, event = actcal.tse$event)
dput(head(actcal.seqe))
```

this returns:

```
structure(list(<pointer: 0x1016201b0>, <pointer: 0x101603940>, 
<pointer: 0x101615330>, <pointer: 0x101615360>, <pointer: 0x10163c860>, 
<pointer: 0x10163c890>), class = c("seqelist", "list"))
```

What does this mean? Is the internal structure not visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, TraMineR uses a C++ structure that is not accessible in R, except throught the provided functions. The results of dput is just the adress of the C pointers to these C++ objects.